# PHP: How to include first digit zero on INSERT STATEMENT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'am trying to INSERT number that has first digit of zero

when i try to add prefix **000012345**

it will only add **12345**

when i try to add prefix **012345**

it will only add **12345**

my datatype is INT(11)

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO circle_call_prefixes (circle, prefix)
         VALUES (?,?)";
         $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
         $stmt ->execute(array($destination , $prefix ));
         $Last_ID = $dbh->lastInsertId();
         $sql_table2 = "INSERT INTO circle_call_destinations 
         (autoNo,destination, source_circle, comment) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
         $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql_table2);
         $stmt -> execute(array($Last_ID, $destination, $source_circle, $comment));
```

thanks

Comment: concatenate your values with zero. like `$value = "0".$value;`

Comment: `int` would ignore the `0` in front. Try with `varchar` and add padding to value `str_pad`.

Comment: Is it possible to change your datatype to TEXT or VARCHAR instead ? .. otherwise leading zero will always be removed

Comment: `TEXT` for a small numeric string? Never that's a big overkill

Comment: If it's actually a numeric value and there's no need to store a leading zero and it's just for display. There's a simle check to determine if it's numeric or just a string of digit: Do you calculate using it like `AVG(col)` or `col *10`? E.g. a phone *number* is a string of digits :)

Comment: @HankyPanky true  .. VARCHAR(11) would be better .. was a blunder from my side

Comment: thanks to all . all of your answer and suggestions are working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySql you can pad fields, if you know the final length, since the length of your column is 11 and if you need to fill it with 0 on left upto the length of your column, then you can use LPAD function like :

```
SELECT LPAD(12345, 11, '0') FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use data type as varchar(11) instead of int(11) if you want 0 as prefix .For integers leading 0's are of no value.

Answer (score 1):

As Somail and Hanky suggested that to keep initial as 0, you should change your data type as varchar instead of int.

But if you want to keep your data type as int then you can go with below approach-

Just change your your data type as "MYCOL INT ZEROFILL"

By this if you insert 1 in this column then it will be stored as 0000000001 and if you insert 125 then 0000000125.

But if you are stick to just your own numbers as just 012345 then use varchar.